# Robot framework module vscode not loading: Error calling "robot.get_version()"

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, robotframework

when adding the mentioned extension, the below error appears and I can't continue the automation:

```
Error calling "robot.get_version()".
If the module: <module 'robot' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x101492470>)>
is a module from your project, please rename it (as it is shadowing the Robot Framework `robot` package)
and restart the Robot Framework Language Server
```

Answer (score 2):

I supposed you have the issue with VS Code Extension named Robot Framework Language Server from Robocorp.

An explained, really clear and good solution is presented in this article:
https://githubhot.com/repo/robocorp/robotframework-lsp/issues/563

It comes from a previous accidental install of Python module 'robot' and uninstalling it is not sufficient.
You have to uninstall and reinstall 'robotframework' with pip.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install extension `Robocorp Code` in VS Code and upgrade your pip robot-framework